# Restore mysql database from a remote dump file

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat

Is it possible to restore a dump file from a remote server?

```
mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
```

Can a dump.sql be located in a remote server? If so how do I refer it in the command above. Copying to the server isn't an option as there is no enough space in the server. I'm on redhat 5

Comment: This is worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768598/mysqldump-backup-and-restore-to-remote-server

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320232/mysql-restore-for-files-on-another-server

Answer (score 2):

1. Implement SSH remote access from the remote server to local
2. run on the remote server 
   cat dump.sql | ssh -c 'mysql -u root -pPASSWORD '

OR

1. Implement MYSQL access from the remote server
2. setup all privileges for root@(REMOTESERVER)
3. run on remote server
   mysql -h mysql.yourcompany.com -u root -p < dump.sql

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?  Pick an available server port (call it 12345)

1. On your mysql box do `nc -l 12345 | mysql -u root -p`
2. On the box with the dumpfile `nc mysqlbox 12345 <  local_dump_file.sql`

Comment: Any unused port -- mysql typically uses 3306 though, so there'll probably be a conflict.

Answer (score -1):

look at the -h options for mysql connections

[MySQL Connection Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html)

Edit:
Oh I misread, you are not trying to load onto a remote server, you want the file to come from a remote server. If you can log into the remote server where the file is you can then:

```
 remotebox:user>>mysql -h <your db box> < local_dump_file.sql
```

Comment: what does <code>removebox:user</code> mean? can you give an example?

Comment: I think it means "remotebox:user"

Comment: so something like 10.0.0.2:myuser>>mysql -u root -p mydb < dump.file right? @mconlin

Comment: yeah, if you are on the remote box, you can mysql -h back to your box, try just logging at first with to be sure the connection is possible. There is potential here for network and user permissions messing this up so watch out for that.

Comment: am getting command not found, what I'm doing wrong here? @mconlin 
$ 10.0.0.2:samdev>>mysql -h10.0.0.2 and am getting 10.0.0.2:samdev: command not found. What could be the issue?

Comment: what is the syntax? @mconlin

Comment: go read up about connection options on the link I initially provided